# Exception in connecting to an API

Tags: android, json, http, exception

```
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
        int responsecode = -1;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        try{
            URL HeadingUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=" + NUMBER_OF_POSTS); // Create a URL object
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) HeadingUrl.openConnection();   //we would make a connection object so as to connect to the url
            // above line may throw Malformed exception
            connection.connect();   // connection to the required url & also may throw IO exception
```

I dont know why the connection object is throwing an io exception while connecting to the mentioned url..and also not able to trace down the cause of it.
please help

here is the log cat msg

```
1525-1525/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.ears, PID: 1525
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected parameter type list size: 0
        at com.android.dex.Dex.parameterTypeIndicesFromMethodIndex(Dex.java:426)
        at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.equalConstructorParameters(ArtMethod.java:106)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructorInternal(Class.java:553)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:529)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1595)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4987)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

OnCreate Method

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (isNetworkEnabled()) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetTitle gettitle = new GetTitle();
        gettitle.execute();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Check your Network Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkEnabled() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo =manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvaialble = false;

    //checking first if the network is not null and then network is connected to web or not
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected())
    {
        isAvaialble = true;
    }
    return isAvaialble;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the calling portion of your AsyncTask? Post the code which will be calling AsyncTask.execute();

Comment: check the edited post now

Comment: What is the possible value of "NUMBER_OF_POSTS" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling the execute() method without parameters and thats the err.

Change your onCreate() to following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (isNetworkEnabled()) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetTitle gettitle = new GetTitle();
        gettitle.execute(new Object[0]);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Check your Network Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, still the same problem now..
in debugging its showing the cause of exception in the line
connection.connect() ;